# How to update pcmanfm?

Tags: pcmanfm

Running Ubuntu 12.04 - looking at the PCmanFM [site](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM) it says the latest version is `1.2.3` (from 14 Oct. 2014) however my version in Synaptic says it is `0.9.10-0ubuntu2` with no option to upgrade.

I have also tried installing with

```
sudo apt-get install pcmanfm
```

and got the message:

> pcmanfm is already the newest version.

Could someone please explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Ubuntu 12.04, in Ubuntu 15.04 it's the 1.2.3 version.